# Create md5sum of file parallel to file dump

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, md5sum

My C program creates output file out.txt.

I've to create md5sum of it.

I know that the command is `md5sum out.txt > md5sum.txt`.

What I want is not to create whole out.txt and then `md5sum out.txt`.

I want both operations to run parallely. Md5sum should be created while file is dumped. So that I could save some time.

Something like,

```
./program > out.txt &
md5sum out.txt > md5sum.txt &
wait
```

Is there a valid way to do this ? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

./program | md5sum > md5sum.txt

This should work for you :).

When you write A | B, both processes already run in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the checksum of file then you can use pipeline.
**like ./program | md5sum > md5sum.txt** 
But in this way you will loose output file.
You can use following syntax 
 **./program | tee > out.txt | md5sum > md5sum.txt** 
This will create *out.txt* file and also calculate md5sum whose output goes to *md5sum.txt*

Comment: It is `tee out.txt` not `tee > out.txt`

Comment: `tee out.txt` gives error that file does not exists broken pipe error

Comment: RTFM [tee(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html); your use as `tee > out.txt` is the same as `cat > out.txt`

Comment: I ran this command on my linux machine and i know the man page of `tee`. You should try this command.

Comment: @ChetanKhilosiya, this is some useful information,upvote for that. But not direct and clear answer to my question. See also, accepted answer.